# #VALUE! Error when trying to call a UDF function into another UDF function

Tags: excel, vba

Simply put, what I am attempting to do is a simple function that would calculate the sample variance of a selected range of cells in excel. The effect is to get a result exactly identical to the excel function =VAR.S()

I have coded in the user-defined function for mean (see below), but the error arises when trying to call my Mean1b function into my Var2a function. If I had simply defined mean as a constant in my variance formula, everything goes smoothly.

My question is, why am I not simply able to pass the input array through my Var2a function, such that it would be accepted by Mean1b function? What would also be the workaround this if I were to continue working in ParamArray?

```
Public Function Mean1b(ParamArray arr() As Variant)
   Dim rtot As Double
   Dim elem As Variant
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim count As Integer

   rtot = 0 'set initial state
   count = 0 'initiate count of elements in the array

    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr) 'loop from lower bound to upper bound of array
        For Each elem In arr(i)
            rtot = rtot + elem.Value
            count = count + 1
        Next elem
    Next i
    Mean1b = rtot / count
End Function

Public Function Var2a(ParamArray arr() As Variant) As Double
    Dim rtot As Double
    Dim elem As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim count As Integer

    mean = Mean1b(arr)
    rtot = 0
    count = 0

    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        For Each elem In arr(i)
            rtot = rtot + (elem.Value - mean) ^ 2
            count = count + 1
        Next elem
    Next i
    Var2a = rtot / (count - 1)
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved it! Turns out all you had to do was to modify this:

`mean = Mean1b(arr)`

to this:

`mean = Mean1b(arr(0))`

Apparently this is required when passing a ParamArray into another function

Comment: "Apparently this is required when passing a ParamArray" - only if the other function also accepts a `ParamArray`, because the parameter *is* an array. If you're passing the parameter array as an argument to a `ParamArray`, then the function is working with an array whose first and only element is ...an array.

Comment: Note that you'll want to use `Long` instead of `Integer`, otherwise you've baked-in a hard limit of 32,767 for the size of your inputs.

Comment: One more thing: `elem.Value` assumes the array is in fact a `Range` object and not just a 2D array of values. This may become a problem.